# how can i source last N lines of a shell script

Tags: unix, shell

for example

> a=1;b=2;c=3;d=4;e=5

the file is 1.sh

> cat 1.sh

```
echo $a
echo $b
echo $c
echo $d
echo $e
```

i use the command

> source 1.sh

i get

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

how can i source the last 3 line of 1.sh?

> tail -n 3 1.sh|xargs -0 sh -c

can not work because the variable can not pass to sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tail -n 3 1.sh > tmp.sh ; source ./tmp.sh ; rm tmp.sh`

If necessary, choose or generate a name that's unlikely to collide with anything else, like `/tmp/tmp$$.sh`.

Comment: thank you for your quick response,is there any way that do not need a temp file?

Comment: If you're using bash: `source <(tail -n 3 1.sh)` should do it.